# SDL's ndk build failing with, <iconv.h> not found

Tags: android-ndk, sdl

Everything works up to this stage, and iconv.h is definitely on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently if you're using a copy of the SDL source that's been `./configured`'d at all, that does something to the include directory that screws up the android build process. There is not supposed to be an iconv dependency with android. Use a fresh copy of the source, and don't configure it.